# Security implications of moving Apache document root outside of /var/www

Tags: apache

I was wondering what, if any, security implications are involved in moving the document root outside of `/var/www` in Apache. I'm not asking ***how***- I'm wondering if I ***should***.

There's a group shared directory used by our staff that resides in `/srv/SHARED`, and we were thinking of doing something like this:

Document root: `/var/www/DOMAIN`, which is a symlink to: `/srv/SHARED/sites/DOMAIN/live`.

This would allow us to update the symlink easily for our deployment scripts and in case we need to rollback to a previous deployment. There will be multiple domains hosted on this server.

While not specific to WordPress, I believe [this article](https://www.wordfence.com/blog/2021/06/service-vulnerabilities-shared-hosting-symlink-security-issue-still-widely-exploited-on-unpatched-servers/) is applicable in that it discusses some security implications of symlinks.

As it stands, the group would own everything inside the `/srv/SHARED` directory, and `www-data` would only own the files/directories needed inside `/srv/SHARED/sites/DOMAIN/live`. We obviously don't want the web server to access anything outside of that directory.

Any insight or suggestions would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign any document root you want, security implications may arise if you assigned a folder that contained sensitive information as document root, so no real issue once you just follow common sense.